# Java - Error on: long n = 8751475143;

Tags: java, long-integer

This number falls into the long range, so why do I get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The literal 8751475143 of type int is out of range
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make it

```
long n = 8751475143L;
```

`L` will make it long literal

by default its `int`

> An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int (§4.2.1). The suffix L is preferred, because the letter l (ell) is often hard to distinguish from the digit 1 (one). [[..]](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/lexical.html)

Comment: Why do you need to do this though?

Comment: @mark as per the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1): *An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int*

Comment: Which is completely different to e.g. C#, where an integer literal without suffix is of the smallest type it would fit into. But the Java approach forces you to make sure you really want to do what you wrote.

Comment: Mark - it's just a slightly silly piece of design, like making bytes signed. Remember it, but don't agonise about it too much.

Answer (score 6):

The target of the assignment isn't taken into account when parsing the literal - so you need the L suffix:

```
long n = 8751475143L;
```

For the most part - and there *are* a few notable exceptions - the type of an expression is determined without much reference to its context. So as per [section 3.10.1 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1), an integer literal is of type `int` unless it has an `l` or `L` suffix, and the range of an integer literal of type `int` is of course limited to the range of `int` itslf.

Answer (score 0):

All numbers in java are treated as `integer`s, unless you say otherwise (or you use a decimal separator - then they are treated as a `float`s).

So, if you write

`long i = 1234;`

java will tread the number `1234` as `integer`, and do the type-cast to `long` for you.

However, if you type:

`long n = 8751475143;`

Java cannot treat `8751475143` as `integer`, because it's out of range. You need to specify, that what you meant was `long`, by adding 'L' at the end:

`long n = 8751475143L;`