# long variable is not accepting a value

Tags: java

I am trying to assign a value to a long variable but eclipse shows compile error. Can anyone work it out what is wrong with this? I have check and am assured that the value is in long's  range.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        **long num = 600851475143;**

        for(long i = num/2; i<1; i--) {
            if(num%i == 0 && isPrime(i) == true) {
                System.out.println(i);
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `L` and make it

```
long num = 600851475143L;
```

---

**Also See**

- [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801003/java-error-on-long-n-8751475143/10801022#10801022)

Answer (score 3):

You have to append `L` to the literal to tell the compiler it's a `long`. Integer literals in Java are `int` by default; since the number you entered doesn't fit in an `int`, the compiler complains.